# How to adjust error box to violin plot using geom_violin?

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

***editing:

```
errbar_lims <- group_by(dt, together) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(mean=mean(score), se=sd(score)/sqrt(n()), 
            upper=mean+(2*se), lower=mean-(2*se))




> dput(dt)
structure(list(ï..count = c(50L, 7L, 21L, 22L, 94L, 58L, 147L, 
4L, 30L, 67L, 91L, 75L, 143L, 15L, 64L, 141L, 39L, 18L, 27L, 
70L, 142L, 95L, 26L, 78L, 8L, 146L, 46L, 138L, 36L, 63L, 66L, 
97L, 56L, 25L, 19L, 59L, 99L, 5L, 33L, 17L, 55L, 98L, 31L, 42L, 
76L, 23L, 44L, 32L, 52L, 60L, 20L, 37L, 140L, 93L, 65L, 87L, 
13L, 68L, 51L, 16L, 152L, 81L, 54L, 35L, 149L, 77L, 90L, 38L, 
48L, 153L, 2L, 14L, 12L, 10L, 3L, 28L, 61L, 71L, 6L, 45L, 69L, 
43L, 53L, 47L, 34L, 92L, 9L, 57L, 145L, 11L, 62L, 49L, 148L, 
144L, 1L, 40L, 24L, 88L, 13L, 96L), condition = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L), together = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Shared Negative", 
"Shared Positive"), class = "factor", label = "together"), second = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Negative Second", "Positive Second"), class = "factor"), 
    experimenter = c(1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L
    ), age = structure(c(23L, 24L, 25L, 23L, 24L, 35L, 25L, 23L, 
    23L, 24L, 23L, 24L, 31L, 23L, 25L, 23L, 20L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 
    27L, 22L, 25L, 25L, 23L, 31L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 23L, 26L, 24L, 
    24L, 26L, 22L, 24L, 23L, 24L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 27L, 26L, 
    63L, 23L, 22L, 32L, 24L, 22L, 23L, 31L, 40L, 24L, 24L, 22L, 
    23L, 38L, 22L, 27L, 29L, 24L, 22L, 25L, 32L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 
    23L, 23L, 56L, 48L, 27L, 25L, 23L, 24L, 21L, 25L, 23L, 27L, 
    31L, 26L, 26L, 24L, 30L, 23L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 25L, 35L, 
    28L, 30L, 21L, 25L, 23L, 37L, 21L, 44L), label = "Age"), 
    sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor", label = "Sex"), 
    q1 = structure(c(0L, 11L, 18L, 0L, 18L, 19L, 9L, 13L, 36L, 
    41L, 29L, 34L, 33L, 53L, 27L, 35L, NA, 40L, 49L, 34L, 38L, 
    48L, 35L, 29L, 23L, 47L, 35L, 69L, 50L, 45L, 60L, 49L, 34L, 
    NA, 43L, 44L, 51L, 20L, 37L, 69L, 36L, 41L, 45L, 60L, 47L, 
    62L, 58L, 47L, 18L, 30L, 52L, 48L, 60L, 51L, 53L, 54L, 42L, 
    52L, 47L, 51L, 56L, NA, 54L, 51L, 47L, 57L, 47L, 66L, 53L, 
    54L, NA, 54L, 57L, 49L, 67L, 80L, 49L, 36L, 58L, 57L, 50L, 
    87L, 51L, 55L, 59L, 70L, 65L, 59L, 61L, 67L, 50L, 63L, 60L, 
    73L, 70L, 88L, 88L, 83L, 100L, 100L), label = "Question 1"), 
    q2 = c(0L, 13L, 12L, 22L, 23L, 19L, 31L, 11L, 71L, 13L, 36L, 
    12L, 33L, 24L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 41L, 50L, 35L, 58L, 39L, 42L, 
    37L, 64L, 48L, 44L, NA, 40L, 57L, 46L, 49L, 37L, 42L, 67L, 
    53L, 51L, 35L, 49L, 65L, 49L, 58L, 51L, 49L, 46L, 59L, 40L, 
    47L, NA, 51L, 53L, 47L, 60L, 51L, 53L, NA, 63L, 52L, 41L, 
    49L, 50L, NA, 53L, 52L, 64L, 54L, 57L, 50L, 57L, 54L, 55L, 
    64L, 62L, 27L, 65L, 70L, 53L, 68L, 65L, 54L, 59L, 53L, 61L, 
    56L, 58L, 69L, 74L, 62L, 56L, 67L, 62L, 58L, 60L, 72L, 78L, 
    100L, 84L, 96L, 100L, 99L), q3 = c(0L, 14L, 18L, NA, 19L, 
    16L, 53L, 66L, 81L, 35L, 36L, 65L, 32L, 73L, 75L, 30L, 64L, 
    44L, 13L, 51L, 62L, 50L, 42L, 51L, 47L, 12L, 60L, 62L, 66L, 
    77L, 55L, 43L, 69L, 70L, 85L, 68L, 50L, 56L, 46L, 97L, 67L, 
    80L, 59L, 63L, 46L, 60L, 35L, 47L, 35L, 52L, 48L, 58L, 62L, 
    51L, 65L, 67L, 65L, 61L, 71L, 58L, 56L, 57L, 54L, 73L, 60L, 
    62L, 57L, 63L, 53L, 54L, 79L, 87L, 59L, 61L, 78L, 16L, 43L, 
    81L, 69L, 69L, 58L, 47L, 49L, 56L, 58L, 51L, 77L, 65L, 61L, 
    67L, 83L, 90L, 81L, 83L, 78L, 66L, 98L, 9L, 71L, 100L), q4 = c(0L, 
    10L, 23L, 33L, 20L, 17L, 7L, 20L, 3L, 41L, 29L, 17L, 32L, 
    0L, 39L, 50L, 22L, 42L, 52L, 43L, 18L, 24L, 46L, 53L, 31L, 
    14L, 31L, 43L, 24L, 41L, 19L, 42L, 38L, 42L, 37L, 69L, 33L, 
    57L, 51L, 7L, 49L, 10L, 44L, 29L, 50L, 24L, 59L, 48L, 63L, 
    46L, 9L, 49L, 44L, 51L, 44L, 43L, 38L, 45L, 12L, 52L, 49L, 
    NA, 53L, 42L, 40L, 46L, 68L, 46L, 53L, 54L, 33L, 41L, 39L, 
    42L, 32L, 41L, 66L, 36L, 21L, 55L, 44L, 61L, 47L, 56L, 61L, 
    57L, 68L, 41L, 39L, 67L, 23L, 47L, 68L, 34L, 61L, 25L, 68L, 
    92L, 70L, 100L), q5 = c(5L, 7L, 15L, 0L, 19L, 17L, 31L, 19L, 
    23L, 19L, 26L, 34L, 35L, 52L, 46L, 44L, NA, 42L, 34L, 18L, 
    34L, 47L, 51L, 34L, 47L, 39L, 57L, 46L, 48L, 43L, 49L, 41L, 
    41L, 42L, 48L, 43L, 50L, 49L, 68L, 43L, 38L, 46L, 46L, 48L, 
    61L, 57L, 50L, 49L, 47L, 51L, NA, 48L, 34L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 
    46L, 54L, 48L, 55L, 57L, NA, 53L, 51L, 58L, 48L, 50L, 64L, 
    57L, 54L, 52L, 53L, 61L, 79L, 58L, 78L, 51L, 64L, 68L, 58L, 
    55L, 59L, 64L, 62L, 60L, 58L, 67L, 63L, 66L, 68L, 72L, 65L, 
    72L, 69L, 75L, 27L, 70L, 95L, 100L, 100L), q6 = c(3L, 13L, 
    14L, 43L, 17L, 23L, 0L, 20L, 11L, 33L, 38L, 3L, 44L, 0L, 
    6L, 50L, 0L, 46L, 34L, 53L, 34L, 19L, 50L, 43L, 47L, 63L, 
    46L, 27L, 18L, 42L, 42L, 41L, 51L, 32L, 43L, 24L, 50L, 52L, 
    11L, 4L, 49L, 31L, 59L, 28L, 61L, 46L, 56L, 50L, 40L, 51L, 
    30L, 47L, 57L, 46L, 46L, 44L, 43L, 42L, 53L, 50L, 50L, 53L, 
    53L, 66L, 30L, 40L, 52L, 39L, 52L, 54L, 51L, 32L, 32L, 64L, 
    43L, 7L, 58L, 31L, 39L, 51L, 57L, 44L, 59L, 62L, 61L, 57L, 
    32L, 39L, 68L, 58L, 83L, 62L, 43L, 32L, 61L, 65L, 60L, 94L, 
    86L, 100L), q7 = c(40L, 20L, 31L, 67L, 18L, 27L, 50L, 49L, 
    29L, 38L, 45L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 56L, 70L, 45L, 43L, 53L, 
    42L, 69L, 53L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 53L, 48L, 80L, 66L, 46L, 48L, 
    61L, 62L, 37L, 69L, 49L, 61L, 69L, 86L, 50L, 68L, 49L, 50L, 
    35L, 44L, 43L, 50L, 62L, 51L, 53L, 50L, 46L, 51L, 53L, 51L, 
    71L, 53L, 87L, 57L, 56L, 54L, 53L, 42L, 69L, 61L, 45L, 47L, 
    53L, 54L, 68L, 73L, 66L, 65L, 56L, 72L, 69L, 71L, 71L, 60L, 
    57L, 63L, 75L, 58L, 61L, 52L, 24L, 69L, 71L, 53L, 94L, 81L, 
    43L, 91L, 61L, 57L, 46L, 95L, 84L, 100L), q8 = c(3L, 25L, 
    13L, 0L, 18L, 27L, 15L, 17L, 13L, 38L, 31L, 29L, 26L, 53L, 
    11L, 36L, 23L, 30L, 46L, 43L, 57L, 39L, 25L, 42L, 63L, 69L, 
    30L, 64L, 47L, 41L, 54L, 42L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 21L, 50L, 47L, 
    50L, 24L, 49L, 45L, 45L, 55L, 47L, 43L, 46L, 49L, 62L, 51L, 
    43L, 47L, 63L, 51L, 48L, 49L, 40L, 54L, 46L, 49L, 58L, 49L, 
    53L, 52L, 41L, 50L, 45L, 47L, 53L, 54L, 50L, 56L, 64L, 39L, 
    57L, 38L, 49L, 43L, 48L, 52L, 58L, 55L, 68L, 62L, 59L, 58L, 
    64L, 68L, 46L, 56L, 31L, 63L, 67L, 71L, 62L, 99L, 82L, 98L, 
    100L, 100L), q9 = c(0L, 13L, 5L, 0L, 18L, 25L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 
    15L, 22L, 64L, 26L, 0L, 51L, 37L, 60L, 43L, 43L, 50L, 17L, 
    38L, 51L, 49L, 28L, 32L, 40L, 13L, 16L, 19L, 36L, 51L, 55L, 
    46L, 35L, 26L, 41L, 48L, 31L, 21L, 43L, 61L, 39L, 40L, 46L, 
    49L, 50L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 87L, 55L, 36L, 51L, 48L, 52L, 42L, 
    53L, 59L, 50L, 41L, 53L, 53L, 52L, 66L, 60L, 56L, 54L, 53L, 
    54L, 25L, 34L, 37L, 50L, 38L, 73L, 46L, 72L, 56L, 52L, 59L, 
    53L, 40L, 62L, 60L, 58L, 64L, 63L, 67L, 59L, 79L, 63L, 95L, 
    39L, 66L, 75L, 72L, 91L, 79L, 100L), q10 = c(0L, 2L, 3L, 
    0L, 18L, 25L, 21L, 17L, 22L, 31L, 24L, 16L, 26L, 53L, 37L, 
    16L, 53L, 40L, 50L, 40L, 61L, 49L, 34L, 44L, 34L, 69L, 47L, 
    37L, 66L, 24L, 49L, 50L, 35L, 42L, 37L, 56L, 50L, 52L, 66L, 
    65L, 51L, 41L, 45L, 62L, 46L, 42L, 49L, 50L, 61L, 53L, 69L, 
    48L, 38L, 51L, 48L, 50L, 69L, 53L, 65L, 58L, 58L, 53L, 53L, 
    51L, 58L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 53L, 54L, 74L, 48L, 68L, 69L, 52L, 
    74L, 65L, 47L, 59L, 56L, 67L, 57L, 70L, 61L, 59L, 67L, 63L, 
    70L, 66L, 53L, 75L, 65L, 72L, 100L, 67L, 100L, 78L, 98L, 
    100L, 100L), score = structure(c(5.1, 12.8, 15.2, 18.33, 
    18.8, 21.5, 21.7, 25.1, 28.9, 30.4, 31.6, 32.7, 34, 36.1, 
    38.2, 39.1, 41.13, 41.3, 41.4, 42, 42.1, 42.2, 42.9, 42.9, 
    43.1, 44.1, 44.3, 45.44, 45.5, 45.5, 45.6, 45.6, 45.8, 46.22, 
    47.1, 47.3, 47.5, 47.7, 47.8, 48.1, 48.1, 48.1, 48.2, 48.4, 
    48.5, 48.6, 48.6, 48.7, 48.89, 48.9, 49.33, 49.7, 50, 50.5, 
    51, 51.33, 51.9, 51.9, 52.9, 52.9, 53.1, 53.17, 53.2, 53.2, 
    53.3, 53.5, 53.6, 53.6, 53.7, 54, 54.11, 54.2, 54.5, 54.5, 
    54.6, 54.9, 54.9, 54.9, 55.4, 56.4, 56.4, 57.9, 58.4, 59, 
    59.6, 59.7, 59.8, 59.9, 60.1, 61.5, 65.2, 65.7, 66.1, 66.4, 
    67.9, 70.2, 74.6, 85.1, 89, 99.9), label = "Evaluation Score")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = "data.frame")
```

I created a basic violin plot with a boxplot, and I want to add an error box. Here is some code:

```
  dplyr::summarize(mean=mean(score), se=sd(score)/sqrt(n()), 
            upper=mean+(2*se), lower=mean-(2*se))

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_violin(data=dt, aes(x=together, y=score, fill=second, color=second)) +
  geom_point(data=errbar_lims, aes(x=together, y=mean), size=3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=errbar_lims$together, ymax=errbar_lims$upper, 
                    ymin=errbar_lims$lower), stat='identity', width=.25) +
  theme_minimal()

print(p)
```

This is what I get:
The errors are only shown for the two groups.
[image]

How can I add define the errors and display an error box to all four violins? I there a way to overlay the error box on the violins? like those:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: could you provide `dt` with `dput(dt)`?

Comment: And also `errbar_lims`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a total of four violins on your plot, because you have placed the factor level `together` along the x axis, and used the column `second` for your fill aesthetic. Each value of `together` therefore has two violins: one for "Negative Second" and one for "Positive Second".

The problem is that when you made the data frame `errbar_lims`, you only grouped by `together`, so if we examine it we will see it does not contain any information about `second`. It only has two rows, so can only produce two error bars:

```r
errbar_lims
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   together         mean    se upper lower
#>   <fct>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Shared Negative  53.3  1.92  57.1  49.4
#> 2 Shared Positive  45.3  2.00  49.3  41.3
```

What you are looking for is a data frame with four rows to cover all 4 possible combinations of `together` and `second`. You could achieve that by doing this:

```r
errbar_lims <- group_by(dt, together, second) %>% 
  summarize(mean  = mean(score), 
            se    = sd(score) / sqrt(n()), 
            upper = mean + (2 * se), 
            lower = mean - (2 * se))
```

If we examine this, we will see it has the four rows that we need for our four error bars:

```r
errbar_lims
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#> # Groups:   together [2]
#>   together        second           mean    se upper lower
#>   <fct>           <fct>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Shared Negative Negative Second  55.7  3.35  62.4  49.0
#> 2 Shared Negative Positive Second  50.9  1.91  54.8  47.1
#> 3 Shared Positive Negative Second  45.0  3.02  51.1  39.0
#> 4 Shared Positive Positive Second  45.5  2.69  50.9  40.2
```

Now we can plot, but we need to remember to tell `geom_point` and `geom_errorbar` that they should be grouped according to the `second` column. We also need to tell them we want the geoms to be dodged so that they are not all plotted between the violins:

```r
ggplot(dt, aes(x = together, fill = second)) +
  geom_violin(aes(y = score, color = second)) +
  geom_point(data = errbar_lims, aes(x = together, y = mean, group = second), 
             size = 3,
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(data = errbar_lims, 
                aes(ymax = upper, ymin = lower, group = second), 
                stat = 'identity', 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
                width = 0.25) +
         theme_minimal()
```

[image]